# Display and calculate input number

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How do i automatically display every time I input number and calculate it.

Then the **pick button** will trigger to calculate the price, my base price would be 100. so if its 2 layers it will be 200 ,

```html
  <br> Layer  <input type="number" min="1" id="cake_layer" name="cake_layer" /> <!-- onchange="updateTotal()" -->
  <input type="button" value="Pick" id="choose" /> 
  
  <br>
  Layer inputed <div class="layer_display"> </div>
  <br>
   Layer Amount <div class="layer_amt"> </div>
```

I really need help. thank you !!!

Comment: What did u mean by `display every time`

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! In order for us to help you better, please update your question so that it shows all relevant code in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also be sure to let us know what you have tried so far to solve your problem. For further information, please refer to the [help article](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) regarding how to ask good questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want to do?

```js
var cakeLayer = document.getElementById("cake_layer"),
  price = 100,
  layerDisplay = document.getElementsByClassName("layer_display")[0],
  layerAmt = document.getElementsByClassName("layer_amt")[0];

cakeLayer.onchange = function(event) {
  var amount = this.value || 0,
    totalPrice = amount * price;

  layerDisplay.innerText = totalPrice;
  layerAmt.innerText = amount;

}
```

```html
<input type="number" min="1" id="cake_layer" name="cake_layer" />
<!-- onchange="updateTotal()" -->
<input type="button" value="Pick" id="choose" />
<br> total price
<div class="layer_display"> </div>
<br> Layer Amount
<div class="layer_amt"> </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by using JavaScript or jQuery. That's the only way to manipulate the DOM.

See this working jsfiddle I made:
https://jsfiddle.net/jw6q53fz/1/

**HMTL**

```
<div>
    <label for="cake_layer">Layer</label>
    <input type="number" class="cake_layer" name="cake_layer" id="cake_layer"/>
    <button id="choose">Pick</button>
</div>  
<div>
    <p>Layer inputed: <span class="layer_display"> </span></p>
    <p>Layer Amount: <span class="layer_amt"> </span></p>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('#choose').on('click', function(){
    var cakeLayerValue = $('#cake_layer').val();
    $('.layer_display').html(cakeLayerValue);
    $('.layer_amt').html(cakeLayerValue * 100);
});
```